# php array_unique method "puts key into array"

Tags: php, array-unique

Im going to parse json to my array by unique values. But here is some problem about array_unique function.
For example:

```
$contract_types = [ "Asset Sale and Purchase Agreement", "Asset Sale and Purchase Agreement", "Concession Agreement" ];
```

and

```
return array_unique($contract_types);
```

gives me: `[{ "0": "Asset Sale and Purchase Agreement", "2": "Concession Agreement" }]`

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: OK. It's worked thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) preserves keys. From PHP docs:

> Note that keys are preserved.

If you wish to reindex the array so it has consecutive integer indexes, use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
return array_values(array_unique($contract_types));
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean that your keys are 0, 2 and you wish you had 0,1 ?

If so, perform a [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) :

```
$contract_types = array_unique($contract_types);

return array_values($contract_types);
```